# Checking client side validation suceeded/failed at server side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, jquery-plugins

How can  i check there is no javascript errors in the webpage from my serverside code ?
I mean only at runtime validation errors , not syntax errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can define an "end" to your javascript code, then you can after this "end" to use ajax to send a confirmation to the server that everything was ok.

Comment: Yes, anyway validation (not syntax) is made to code that already run.

Comment: i didnt understood , what i need to do for achieve this?

Comment: Suppose you have 100 lines of javascript code, at line 101 add an ajax call to your server that say that everything is ok. If validation error occurred, the browser won't reach this line. About using ajax and WebMethod look at: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/